# VBA Copy Data from one workbook against reference in another

Tags: excel, vba

I have browsed the web for an answer but can't find one to help.  What I am trying to do is open a workbook and copy the data from the "Data" tab (B2 to I2) into my main workbook under the "Register" tab.  The catch is that I need the data to paste against the corresponding reference.  In the workbook I am opening the reference is in A2 and in the existing workbook the reference it needs to look for is in Column A.

I have managed to write a code that pastes the data into the Row number of the reference but that's no good as it has to be the actual value in Column A that it looksup and pastes against.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated please!

```
Sub Import()
Dim WB2op As String, CurWB As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, nextrow As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Register")
Set CurWB = ThisWorkbook
WB2op = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose File", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")
If WB2op = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
Else
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(WB2op)
With Sheets("Data")    'change name to suit
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
End With

If WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("A2") >= 0 Then
Row = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("A2") + 1
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Range("N" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("B2")
ws.Range("O" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("C2")
ws.Range("P" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("D2")
ws.Range("Q" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("E2")
ws.Range("R" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("F2")
ws.Range("S" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("G2")
ws.Range("T" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("H2")
ws.Range("U" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("I2")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

WB2.Close False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by adding a MATCH option as per the below:

```
Sub Import()
Dim WB2op As String, CurWB As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, nextrow As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Register")
Set CurWB = ThisWorkbook
WB2op = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose File", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")
If WB2op = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
Else
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(WB2op)
With Sheets("Data")    'change name to suit
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
End With

If WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("A2") >= 0 Then
On Error Resume Next
Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("A2"), ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Range("N" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("B2")
ws.Range("O" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("C2")
ws.Range("P" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("D2")
ws.Range("Q" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("E2")
ws.Range("R" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("F2")
ws.Range("S" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("G2")
ws.Range("T" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("H2")
ws.Range("U" & Row).Value = WB2.Sheets("Data").Range("I2")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
```

WB2.Close False
End Sub